# Pushplugin- Unable to register the device (IOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using Phonegap Pushplugin for my push notifications. Added logs in both methods. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method never got executed. It is not even failing on `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`. Not sure what is the issue here.

I uploaded IOS distribution certificate (Not APN) to steroids build service and uploaded APN Prod profile to AdHoc build. I am getting the prompt for push notifications and I can see that notifications are enabled for my app. Issue is, I am not getting the token.

Looked at the following link for [debugging steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG21)

[Plugin link](https://github.com/francimedia/PushPlugin)

I am using the following code for registration.

```
function registerDevice(){
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(
                              tokenHandler,
                              errorHandler, {
                                  "badge":"true",
                                  "sound":"true",
                                  "alert":"true",
                                  "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
                              });
}

var onNotificationAPN = function(event) {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    if ( event.alert )
    {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound )
    {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge )
    {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler,
                                                       event.badge);
    }
}

function tokenHandler (result) {
    steroids.logger.log("Tokenhandler called with result");
    steroids.logger.log(result);

    alert(result);

}

function errorHandler (error) {
    steroids.logger.log("errorHandler called with result");
    steroids.logger.log(error);
    alert('error = ' + error);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update- 07/30/14

I downloaded PersistentConnectionLogging.mobilecondig and I was able see the generated token. I was able to send a notification to my phone using this token.

tokenHandler and onNotificationAPN still not getting fired. Issue is clearly on Cordova side or in my Javascript.

Is this plugin even working on Cordova 3.1/3.5 ? It is frustrating that there is no community support on this plugin.

Any ideas.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.
did you solved the issue?!

Comment: Official plugin is not working. Use this https://github.com/dfilip/PushPlugin for IOS8 functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i'm implementing push notifications:

1. Handle the certificates. [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)
2. Register and get the token. [Tutorial](http://davehiren.blogspot.in/2012/03/get-device-token-for-apple-push.html)
3. Store the token using NSUserDefaults.
4. Create a custom plugin and pass the token from objective-c to javascript by creating a custom plugin using a JS bridge. [Tutorial](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/)